# Meaning of 'ran' in German?

Tags: idiom

While reading a graded reader for German learners (*Momente in München*) I ***ran*** across the expression "Ran an die Arbeit" and wanted to understand why it means "Get to work"?

I searched in several places and realized that I didn't know what 'ran' meant here. Was it a verb? A verb prefix? To my surprise, I received no help when looking up 'ran' in [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=german&query=ran), [google translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=ran), [deepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/ran) or [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/ran). The [free dictionary defines](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/ran) 'ran' as 'come on, go it" which doesn't make much sense (especially the "go it" part). But it made me think 'ran' is perhaps an interjection that is used idiomatically like "come on" sometimes is in English. That's the best I can figure so far.

A search for ["ran an" at Tatoeba.org](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=Ran%20an&from=deu&to=eng) gives several examples. Here are some simple ones with their translations. Some of them seem to fit the "come on" translation, but not all.

> Nun mal ran an die Arbeit (Now let's get down to work)
>   Ran an den Speck! (Go ahead! Don't be shy!)
>   Geh nicht an dieses Telefon ran! (Don't pick up that phone)
>   Tom lässt keinen an sich ran (Tom is very private)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's short for **heran**. Same as *raus, rein, rauf, runter, rüber*.

> Nun (gehen wir) mal (he)ran an die Arbeit.
>
> (Geh) (he)ran an den Speck!

These use an implicit *gehen* as another complication.

> Geh nicht an dieses Telefon (he)ran!

Nobody would use *heran* in this example though, as *rangehen* has become a verb on its own, meaning *to pick up a phone*. You could say

> Geh nicht ran!

and everyone understands it as they should not pick up the phone. Your example has an additional *an dieses Telefon* which I understand as a pointer to a certain telephone. Pick up the other ones as much as you want to. Just not that red one. Putin is on that line. Okay?

There's another verb *herangehen* which means *to approach*.

> An diese Sache gehst du besser anders (he)ran.

In this example, *heran* is idiomatic but you will sometimes hear *ran*, too.

> Tom lässt keinen an sich (he)ran.

Again, *ranlassen* has become a verb on its own, meaning *to get in touch*. Unlike *rangehen/herangehen*, *heranlassen* means the same as *ranlassen*. So you can use both *ran* and *heran* in this example.

Comment: What a great answer! These are the kind of things that are very difficult for a learner pick up, but your explanations are quite helpful. Vielen Dank!

Comment: related: "Ich komm nicht dran!" (*I cannot get at it/cannot reach it* or *it's never my turn*) is contracted in a similar fashion from **da**ran, cf. "Drum und Dran"

Comment: @dlatikay that's *dar-an* more than *da-ran*. The confusion just goes to show that *ran* has been fully lexicalized (since 16th c. according to Grimm), wheras *dar* (there) has become obsolete. I still object to explaining these as mere contractions instead of analogic leveling due to assorted examples (e.g. *komm rein*, with *rein* as an archaic verb "to wash", "reine machen"; Gothic *usrinnan, urrinnan*, Ger *er-*, En *arise*, *rise*; Ger *nieder*, which is not a contraction neither), but I'm getting nowhere with this and shouldn't fight windmills everytime it's brought up.